# Unable to declare Swift implicitly unwrapped optional as a constant

Tags: swift

This is a code sample from *The swift programming language* ibook:

```
class Product {
    let name: String!

    init?(name:String) {
        if name.isEmpty { return nil }
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

It doesn't work unless name is declared as variable instead of a constant. Have there been introduced changes with regard to this issue in Swift 1.2 that I'm not aware of?

Comment: If you're getting a compiler error or warning, please include that in the question.  Also, do you have a link to exactly where you found this code sample?

Answer (score 6):

This is due to a change in 1.2  Now, before you return `nil` from a class's failable initializer, you must set all the properties to valid value.  The reason being, the `deinit` for a class still runs even after the initializer fails, and for correct code, it needs to know that all the properties are validly initialized (also bear in mind the class may be a subclass, and the inheriting class might also rely on valid initialization of properties after *its* initializer fails).

Implicitly unwrapped optionals are initialized to `nil` by default – but only if they are declared `var`.  If they are declared with `let`, then they are immutable and so can only be initialized once, so can’t start off as `nil` and then change later.  Hence, the `var` version works, but the `let` version doesn’t.

Note, in the recent update to the Swift book, the code is slightly different – it initializes `name` first, then fails:

```
class Product {
     let name: String!
     init?(name: String) {
         self.name = name
         if name.isEmpty { return nil }
     }
}
```

Also note, structs don’t have the requirement to initialize all their members before failing, only classes (presumably because structs don’t have the complications of `deinit` or inheritance).

Comment: The Swift book did change.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26496022/2792531) has identical code from this question and suggests that the code in this question used to work as-is.

Comment: So it's due to changes introduced in Swift 1.2. Thanks for all answers.  Is there an updated version of the book? I didn't find it in iTunes.

Comment: You can delete and redownload the Swift book to get the latest, not sure if it is supposed to update automatically or let you re-download without deleting.