# Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals in Swift does not seem to work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, option-type

I am following the The Swift Programming Language book to investigate strong reference cycle. One of the examples that should be working cannot be compiled in Xcode. I don't understand why the code is broken.

On this [chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), there is an example that looks like this:

[image: This example won't compile in Xcode]

When I try to compile this code in Xcode the this error was thrown: **'self' used before all stored properties are initialized**. However, I think it should have been able to compile because I set capitalCity to be Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals that is nil by default, so after I set **self.name = name** all stored properties should be already properly set.

What do I miss here? What changes are needed to make the code compile?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: lazy var capitalCity = { City(..., country: self}() then don't set it in the init

Comment: Roy Li, just to be honest. Let us know your fix/solution for this example from the book!? But note, you should keep the sense of this example there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let` statements don't have default initialization of optionals to nil, because otherwise writing `let foo:Bar!` would give you a `foo` that was always nil and you couldn't initialize it in a subsequent statement.

The reason `var` is appropriate is that you want default initialization to nil to occur so you can initialize your `City` object with the self reference in order to finally initialize your actual `capitalCity` value which is really double initialization.

The code has a circular class dependency by design, so this is a side effect of that design.

This behavior of `let` is new in Swift 1.2, try the example in Xcode 6.2 or earlier and you will find that it compiles.

Comment: Interesting that the book in question was actually updated for Swift 1.2, as there described Swift's Sets etc. But they just didn't fix the previous code. Anyway, my initial answer was right! I can only admit that I shouldn't write about setting up let in initializer, but it was obvious actually!

Answer (score 2):

As the initializer has not set up the object yet, you cannot initialise another one with it.

You need to initialize the city and then set the property.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet that shows how to do that? I think in order to create a new city object I still need self right?

Comment: Why dont you make City a Struct inside Country?

Answer (score 0):

Just Change (let to var)

```
let capitalCity: City!
```

To

```
var capitalCity: City!
```

This happens, probably, because it cannot be a constant value, since we set it up during init.

**update:**

I have NO idea why I'm down voted!. This is the example from the book, and does NOT compile. But if you change let to var as I said, you'll get it work!

Who can offer here a code modification, so that the code FROM THE BOOK can be compiled!?

I can only admit that I shouldn't write about setting up let in initializer, but I think it's obvious I didn't mean that you cannot set up regular let in initialiser

Comment: No, you can initialize a constant in initializers.

Comment: But sometimes you really need a constant correct? I think we need a way to do that appropriately instead of taking shortcut like this.

Comment: You are right @RoyLi, let still applies until you set the value.

Comment: This is the example from the book, and does NOT compile. But if you change let to var as I said, you'll get it work!

Comment: To NobadyNada this is an OPTIONAL constant

Comment: To Roy Li, I also read the same chapter from the Swift book and encountered the same problem (it does not compile). And if you ONLY change let to var you get it work. It should work with let, but DON'T

Comment: could you post a link to which book and where? I'd be more inclined to cast an upvote.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID51 

This is ARC in Swift example with City/Country

Comment: similar topic related to changes in swift 1.2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956702/unable-to-declare-swift-implicitly-unwrapped-optional-as-a-constant