# Implicitly Unwrapped Optional when a constant that cannot be defined during initialisation, But Error Comes

Tags: swift, initialization

By Drewag in his answer to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals)

> Every member constant must have a value by the time initialization is complete. Sometimes, a constant cannot be initialized with its correct value during initialization, but it can still be guaranteed to have a value before being accessed.
>
> Using an Optional variable gets around this issue because an Optional is automatically initialized with nil and the value it will eventually contain will still be immutable. However, it can be a pain to be constantly unwrapping a variable that you know for sure is not nil. Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals achieve the same benefits as an Optional with the added benefit that one does not have to explicitly unwrap it everywhere.

The following code defines two classes, `Country` and `City`, each of which stores an instance of the other class as a property. Every country must have a capital city and every city must always belong to a country.

```
class Country {
    let name: String
    var capitalCity: City! //why I can't use let!
    init(name: String, capitalName: String){
        self.name = name
        self.capitalCity = City(name: capitalName, country: self)
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("\(name) has been de-initialized the city \(capitalCity.name) is gone with with the country")
    }
    
}

class City{
    let name: String
    unowned let country: Country
    init(name: String, country: Country){
        self.name = name
        self.country = country
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("The city \(name) has been de-initialized ")
    }
}

    var country = Country(name: "Canada", capitalName: "Ottawa")
}
```

However, if I changed the line `var capitalCity: City!` into `let capitalCity: City!`, the compiler given out the following error warning.

[image]

**Question**: Isn't that we can use Implicitly Unwrapped Optional when a constant that cannot be defined during initialization? What's the error here?

Comment: There's a similar SO question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956702/unable-to-declare-swift-implicitly-unwrapped-optional-as-a-constant), although its answer provides a different point of view on the topic

Comment: I think the question should include the warning as text so it shows up in the search engines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part is here:

```
City(name: capitalName, country: self)
```

You are definitely using `self` in the expression which is executed before the assignment to the property `capitalCity`.

If you want to use `self` in any of the expressions, it needs to be in the second phase of [two phase initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID216), which means all properties needs to be initialized before the usage of `self`.

With using `var`, Swift assigns a default initial value `nil` for the property `capitalCity`. So the property can be considered as "already initialized", so, you can use `self` after you have initialized another property `name`.

(You know giving `nil` to a let-constant of `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` is ridiculous.)

By the way `private(set) var` is often used in similar cases:

```
    private(set) var capitalCity: City!
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation. I think Drewag's description maybe wrong Or I understand it wrong. I was also curious that how the Implicit Unwrapped Option first give the constant a nil and then give it a unchanged value