# Failable initializers and stored properties

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, initialization, swift2

I have the following class:

```
class Foo {
    let a : Int?
    let b : Int?

    init?(){

    }
}
```

I get the error *"constant self.a used before being initialised"* in the failable initialiser. What on earth is the compiler talking about? I haven't used `a` at all yet!

Comment: i agree, that is really stupid message ... so or so, you constants a and b must be initialized before the constructor returns (valid class instance, or nil)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that each property declared with `let` in a `class` must be populated before the `init` does return.

In your case the `init` is not populating the 2 constant properties.

In Swift 2.1 each constant property of a `class` must be populated even when a failable initializer does fail.

```
class Foo {
    let a: Int?
    let b: Int?

    init?() {
        return nil // compile error
    }
}
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495586/best-practice-to-implement-a-failable-initializer-in-swift/26497229#26497229).

### Struct

On the other hand you can use a `struct` where a `failable initializer` can return `nil` without populating all the `let` properties.

```
struct Person {
    let name: String

    init?(name:String?) {
        guard let name = name else { return nil }
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Comment: @cfisher: look at the link I added at the end of my answer, there is the answer provided by Chris Lattner (the creator of Swift)