# Can I throw from class init() in Swift with constant string loaded from file?

Tags: swift

I'd like my class *init()* in Swift to throw an error if something goes wrong with loading a file into a string within the class. Once the file is loaded, the string will not be altered, so I would prefer to use *let*. This works:

```
class FileClass {    
    var text: NSString = ""   
    init() throws {   
        do {
            text = try NSString( contentsOfFile: "/Users/me/file.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ) }
        catch let error as NSError {
            text = ""
            throw error
        }      
    }
}
```

but when I replace

```
var text: NSString = ""
```

with

```
let text: NSString
```

I get an **All stored properties of a class instance must be initialized before throwing from an initializer** error.

I've tried various approaches such as to make *text* optional

```
let text: NSString?
```

but haven't found any that work. It it possible to have *text* be loaded from a file, immutable, and for *init()* to throw an error? Can I have my cake and eat it three?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe, you have to look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/26496022/3527499

Comment: Thanks, @Hamsternik, I must have read that post about 5 times before I finally put this one up. It does contain some great insights, although it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### [Update] Swift Version >= 2.2

Since Swift 2.2 you can break the execution of a class initialiser without the need of populating all stored properties

```
class FileStruct {
    let text: String

    init() throws {
        do {
            text = try String(contentsOfFile: "/Users/me/file.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ) }
        catch let error as NSError {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

### Swift Version <= 2.1

Currently in Swift `class` you cannot break the execution of an initialiser before every stored property has been initialized.

On the other hand, you don't have this constraint with `structs` so

```
struct FileStruct {
    var text: String

    init() throws {
        do {
            text = try String(contentsOfFile: "/Users/me/file.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ) }
        catch let error as NSError {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

You can also avoid the do/catch block

```
struct FileStruct {
    var text: String

    init() throws {
        text = try String(contentsOfFile: "/Users/me/file.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
}
```

Finally I replaced `NSString` with `String` since we are using Swift, not Objective-C ;-)

Comment: Thanks @appzYourLife, that works for me. And thanks for the kick re String--old habits come hard to break :)

Answer (score 16):

You can use a [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17) instead, as is more suited for this kind of scenarios.

```
class FileClass {
    let text: String
    init?() {
        guard let fileContents = try? NSString( contentsOfFile: "/Users/me/file.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ) else {
            text = ""
            return nil
        }
        text = fileContents as String
    }
}
```

or, if you want to print the error:

```
class FileClass {
    let text: String
    init?() {
        do {
            text = try String( contentsOfFile: "/Users/me/file.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding )
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error while reading: \(error)")
            text = ""
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is easier than with a throwing initializer, as you can use `if-let` or `guard-let`:

```
if let file = FileClass() {
}
```

, or

```
guard let file = FileClass() else {
    return
}
```

versus

```
let file: FileClass
do {
    file = FileClass()
} catch {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Cristik! It is cleaner, but don't I lose the information about what the error was? I find it helpful in debugging to bring up a modal dialog box with the error description.

Comment: You can do/catch in the initializer if you want to print the error, I added sample code for this too. And you can display an error message to inform the user if you detect the initializer returned nil.

Comment: Could you not do `if let file = try FileClass() {` ??

Comment: @Kudit did you mean `try?` - with a question mark after `try`? If yes, then yes, this is also possible, see the other answer.