# Init UIImage with new params

Tags: swift

how I can do new init like a

> Attention: I need **init**, not **static func**

```
extension UIImage {

    convenience init?(named: String, in bundle: Bundle? = nil, compatibleWith collection: UITraitCollection? = nil, rendring: UIImageRenderingMode) {
        self.init(named: named, in: bundle, compatibleWith: collection)
        self = self.imageWithRenderingMode(rendring) // error
        return
    }

}
```

but I have error for it implementation

> Error: Cannot assign to value: 'self' is immutable

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46600262/6382196) answer for your question.

Comment: I checked it before, and it's not it

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

I wrote it in Swift 4.1, you can make required changes.

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(named: String, in bundle: Bundle? = nil, compatibleWith collection: UITraitCollection? = nil, rendring: UIImageRenderingMode) {
        if let image = UIImage(named: named, in: bundle, compatibleWith: collection) {
            if let cgImage = image.withRenderingMode(rendring).cgImage {
                self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```